# In Flutter, I want to send a notification to the user every day at a certain time

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter, I want to send a notification to the user every day at a certain time (example: pm 8.00). How can I do that. (I'm doing a medicine reminder.) I tried to do it with flutter_local_notifications package but failed. Can you post sample code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local notification flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215211/local-notification-flutter)

Comment: @Rohan Thacker Sorry, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using [alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus) to run a background service
or you can usr the [background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) which i guess suits you best